# Need to fix CSS so DIVs will not overlap

Tags: css, html

I have a template that shows a main image and thumbnails under it.
Each product might have a different number of thumbnail images where each image might have a different aspect ratio.

In order to make the thumbnails look nice i scaled all the thumbnails:

```
#product-thumbnail {
    height: 100px;
}

#product-thumbnail a img {
    height: 100%;
}
```

All of these thumbnails are in a container that is 630px wide, if i have multiple thumbnails, they are added to a second row which overlaps my description text.

i tried using the clear: both on my description div but it did not work.

jsFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/7eY3M/1/

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you put it on jsFiddle.net instead? Makes it a little easier for people who'd like to help.

Comment: Fyi, the plural `s` never has an apostrophe before it.

Comment: What do you want to happen when there are too many photos for a single row? Also try putting the problem on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Do you have a page we can have a look at? You can probably get better advice that way.

Answer (score 0):

~EDIT~

The better way would be to use individual dives with height 100px inside of a div each with the float:left style applied.  In this style, it will keep the images in a line, while allowing them to 'wrap', instead of forcing them to overflow.  This should fix everything. also note, USE display: inline-block; in your 
    `<div id="product-thumbnail">`
Failure to do so results in odd placement of the description, as dose useing display: block or disply: inline.

Css

    `#product-thumbnail {`
    `display: inline-block;`
    `min-height: 100px;`
    `float:none;`
    `}`
    `.thumb`
    `{height=100px;<br>float:left;}`

`<div id="product-thumbnail"> 
 
    <div class="thumb"> 
    <img src=img1> 
    </div> 

    <div class="thumb"> <img src=img2> </div>`

Comment: Wolf-Kun: i get a small scroll bar next to the thumbnails row..  in case there are multiple thumbnails, i want the second row to push the description down and not overlap it.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @uot i want the thumbnails to push down the description and not overlap it

Comment: Oh, sorry.  Looking at this, your problem is with overflow.  When the second line comes in, you have more content than div, thus leading to the issue of them 'overflowing' the container.  just like overflowing a glass of water will result with water on your table, this is resulting with images overflowing onto your description.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #product-thumbnail {
        display: block;
    }

    #product-thumbnail a img {
        vertical-align: middle;
        height: 100px;
        margin: 5px;
        box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px #909090;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px #909090;
        -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px #909090;
    }
```

Move the 100px height to the images themselves, not the containing div.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7eY3M/3/)